# Windows doesn't boot from grub after installing on second drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.10, windows-10

I'm on a Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga s1 running Ubuntu 15.10.

Just yesterday I installed a second SSD in my laptop.  I removed the main drive with Ubuntu, installed Windows 10 onto the second drive, then reinserted the main drive and ran `sudo update-grub`.  When I rebooted, I saw both Ubuntu and Windows 10, but now when I boot into Windows I'm stuck on a purple screen.

What's weird is that if I load BIOS and select which drive to boot from, I can access Windows through grub just fine.  But when I change the boot order to prioritize either the main or secondary drive I get the same issue (related note, should Windows Boot Loader be listed very high up in the boot order?).

I've downloaded and used the boot-repair utility, and I've also ran some commands within the grub console with no luck.

For reference, here is the boot-repair pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14473911/

One solution I've found recommends booting into Windows and running `bootrec/fixmbr` and `bootrec/fixboot`, but it seems like these commands will replace grub, and I don't want to lose access to Ubuntu.

Any ideas on what I could do to be able to load Windows from grub without selecting the right disk from BIOS?

Quick update:
If I load BIOS at all and then boot to Windows it works fine.  Otherwise if I just turn on my computer and select Windows, I get the purple screen.

## **Found a solution:**

The fix I found was to disable quick-booting in windows.  It's listed right in the pastebin that windows 10 was in an unsafe state and could not be booted, and to disable quick-boot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new script file in /etc/grub.d, called 12_custom, with this code:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo "Adding Windows 10 to GRUB 2 menu"
cat << EOF
menuentry "Windows 10" {
     set root=(hd1,1)
     chainloader (hd1,1)+1
   }
EOF
```

The hd1 corresponds to disk 2, and /dev/sdb, but hd0 is disk 1, or /dev/sda. You may need root access to create the file. Make it executable with chmod +x 12_custom. Update your GRUB with sudo update-grub. Reboot to see if you get to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: So this created a new grub option called 'Windows 10'. Selecting it instead of 'Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sdb1)' resulted in the same purple screen.  On another note, my 30_os-prober file in /etc/grub.d/ looks very similar to the file you just had me create in that it sets the root=(hd1,msdos1), but chainloader is +1 instead of (hd1,1)+1.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't of any help, then ignore my answer. I'm probably just as lost in this as you are. Have you seen this post? http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows Following some of the steps, you could try and restore GRUB on the hard drive you are booting from.