# Grey Screen after Windows 10 boot from grub

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, ubuntu-mate

I have a triple boot setup on my laptop. Two Linux distros and windows. I started with ubuntu and then added windows afterwards. I then mounted my drive and repaired grub. I setup ubuntu perfectly. Now I am ready to work on windows but all I get is this [grey screen](https://pasteboard.co/IrtD46N.jpg) when I boot. Does anyone know how to fix this while keeping my ubuntu install?

Comment: According to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/720235/windows-doesnt-boot-from-grub-after-installing-on-second-drive?rq=1 a similar problem was in that case fixed by disabling "quick-booting" in windows. Maybe you could try that?

Comment: @Elias the problem with that is I cannot get into windows period its just this gray screen forever. Should I just reinstall and before fixing grub change that setting then?

Comment: Yes maybe reinstalling windows is needed. No fun having to reinstall, but at least it may be a possible way forward.

Comment: @Elias yeah that will be the 9th time I have installed an os on that laptop in a week lol. Better than not having windows though.

Comment: @Elias So I did I reinstalled and turned off quick boot. I also tried installing new graphics drivers because a different thread said that worked. Nothing so far. I also tried to do what I call a red neck dual boot. Where I load windows in uefi and linux in legacy. Sadly it didn't work because Linux has already set the drive in MBR. So I am really in a tough spot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can happen due to Bitlocker encryption of the drive. What you can try to do if you can get into ubuntu you can try a tool by Daniel Richter called 'grub-customizer'.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

Once you open the tool, click File -> Install to MBR....

Once you do this, reboot and when you choose your Windows install from the GRUB menu, it should ask you for Bitlocker recovery key instead of grey screen.

Good Luck.
M.

Comment: Is bitlocker a default thing for windows, I've never heard of it? Not big on windows. I never setup encryption on my drives because it required LVM and you can't add windows to the LVM. I can get into both Linux partitions fine its just windows doing this. I had just given up on my windows partition and eraced it today. An older CS major told me nothing in our degree path needs windows and the school highly recommends Linux especially manjaro. (Not doing that though I like my current setup)

Comment: No I think you need to turn on bitlocker encryption manually. Try the mbr trick, it could work.

Comment: @Madser please answer questions posted as comments on your posts as comments, you should be able to comment on your own answer.

Comment: @Madser I might give this a shot as a final go but in my bit of research bitlocker is a windows pro edition thing I have home. I also never messed with any of that. Idk though what would the install to MBR do other than install grub to my MBR which it already is?